# Rewriting questions by editing

Tags: discussion

See, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264168/derivative-of-compositum-function-with-log) where the content of the question is essentially entirely rewritten by edits, when there were already several answers (including an accepted one).

Should edits like this be rolled back? Should they be left alone? Should they be flagged?

Comment: I vote for rollback. It's in the spirit of holiday sales.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the user wants to ask a new question, they should post a new question [[1](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814/edit-and-rephrase-or-ask-new-question), [2](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/can-i-change-the-existing-question-to-a-new-one)]. Roll it back without mercy. $\scriptscriptstyle{</\text{grinch}>}$

Comment: Thanks both. I had thought that would be the opinion, but I don't like doing this stuff unless I'm fairly sure and couldn't find a reference!